# CouchBase-lite - Context in Manager cannot be applied

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nosql, couchbase-lite

I am following the [instruction](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.4/installation/java/index.html) to set up CouchBase-lite in IntelliJ Ubuntu.

The problem is that JavaContext cannot be applied to. Any idea why ?

```
package com.couchbase.HelloCBL;

import com.couchbase.lite.*;
import com.couchbase.lite.replicator.Replication;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Enable logging
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger("app");
    log.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    JavaContext context = new JavaContext();

    // Create a manager
    Manager manager = null;
    try {
            manager = new Manager(context, Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS); // THIS LINE DOES NOT COMPILE
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Create or open the database named app
    Database database = null;
    try {
            database = manager.getDatabase("app");
    } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // The properties that will be saved on the document
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put("title", "Couchbase Mobile");
    properties.put("sdk", "Java");

    // Create a new document
    Document document = database.createDocument();

    // Save the document to the database
    try {
            document.putProperties(properties);
    } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Log the document ID (generated by the database)
    // and properties
    log.info(String.format("Document ID :: %s", document.getId()));
    log.info(String.format("Learning %s with %s", (String) document.getProperty("title"), (String) document.getProperty("sdk")));

    // Create replicators to push & pull changes to & from Sync Gateway.
    URL url = null;
    try {
            url = new URL("http://localhost:4984/hello");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Replication push = database.createPushReplication(url);
    Replication pull = database.createPullReplication(url);
    push.setContinuous(true);
    pull.setContinuous(true);

    // Start replicators
    push.start();
    pull.start();

  }
}
```

error message in line

```
manager = new Manager(context, Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
```

error message

**Manager (com.couchbase.lite.Context,ManagerOptions) in Manager cannot be applied to (com.couchbase.lite.JavaContext,ManagerOptions)**

Answer (score 1):

There was a jar file in **default-java/jre/lib/ext/couchbase-lite-java-1.4.1.jar** conflicting with the class